# Values are set when manual trigger change on SELECT but not when triggering from inside a function, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am building some DOM elements dynamically as you may see in the snippet below.  The idea is as follow:

- If I change the `SELECT` and my choice is `Yes/No` then build a set of elements and insert them inside the DOM.
- If I click on the button then some values should be set dynamically for those previous constructed elements

If you follow this path everything works as expected.

- I would expect by clicking on the button and because the `load_edit_question`  function is triggering a change on the `SELECT` to  get the same results but if you click the button only those values gets undefined.

What I am missing here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = [{
      field_id: 294249,
      field_seq: 36,
      field_type_id: 8,
      form_id: 9926,
      is_base_grid: null,
      option_desc: "Yes",
      option_id: 364371,
      other_required: 0
    }, {
      field_id: 294249,
      field_seq: 36,
      field_type_id: 8,
      form_id: 9926,
      is_base_grid: null,
      option_desc: "No",
      option_id: 364372,
      other_required: 0
    }],
    i = 1,
    k = 1,
    container_yes_no = $("#options_yes_no"),
    field_type = $("#field_type_id"),
    content = '<label>Options</label>\n' +
    '<div id="options_yes_no">\n' +
    '    <div class="row-fluid">\n' +
    '        <div class="span2 text-center"></div>\n' +
    '        <div class=\'span6\'>\n' +
    '            <input type="text"\n' +
    '                   class="options"\n' +
    '                   name="option_desc[]"\n' +
    '                   style="width:98%"\n' +
    '                   value="Yes"\n' +
    '                   data-option_field_id=""\n' +
    '                   data-option_id=""\n' +
    '            />\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '        <div class="span2">\n' +
    '            <label class="checkbox">\n' +
    '                <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="option_other_required" name="other_required[]"/> Other\n' +
    '            </label>\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '        <div class="span2">\n' +
    '            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-option"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>\n' +
    '            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-option"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '    </div>\n' +
    '    <div class="row-fluid">\n' +
    '        <div class="span2 text-center"></div>\n' +
    '        <div class=\'span6\'>\n' +
    '            <input type="text"\n' +
    '                   class="options"\n' +
    '                   name="option_desc[]"\n' +
    '                   style="width:98%"\n' +
    '                   value="No"\n' +
    '                   data-option_field_id=""\n' +
    '                   data-option_id=""\n' +
    '            />\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '        <div class="span2">\n' +
    '            <label class="checkbox">\n' +
    '                <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="option_other_required" name="other_required[]"/> Other\n' +
    '            </label>\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '        <div class="span2">\n' +
    '            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-option"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>\n' +
    '            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-option"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '    </div>\n' +
    '</div>\n';

  field_type.change(function() {
    var field_type_id = $(this).find('option:selected'),
      field_type_name = field_type_id.data('alias');

    switch (field_type_name) {
      case 'yes_no':
        container_yes_no.html(content);
        var i = 1,
          k = 1;

        container_yes_no.find(":text").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("id", "option_desc_" + i);
          console.log("option_desc_" + i);
          i++;
        });

        container_yes_no.find(":checkbox").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("id", "option_other_" + k);
          k++;
        });

        break;
      default:
        console.log(field_type_name);
        break;
    }
  }).trigger('change');

  $("#me").on("click", function() {
    load_edit_question(field_type, options);
  });
});

function load_edit_question(select_el, options) {
  select_el.trigger('change');
  loadq(options);
}

function loadq(options) {
  console.log(options);

  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var option = options[i],
      curr_opt_desc = $("#option_desc_" + (i + 1)),
      curr_option_other = $("#option_other_" + (i + 1)),
      fullId = option.field_id + '_' + option.option_id;

    curr_opt_desc.val(option.option_desc);
    curr_option_other.prop('checked', option.other_required === 1);
    curr_opt_desc.data("option_id", option.option_id);
    curr_opt_desc.data("option_field_id", option.field_id);

    console.log(fullId);
    console.log(curr_opt_desc.val());
    console.log(curr_opt_desc.data("option_id"));
    console.log(curr_opt_desc.data("option_field_id"));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Options</label>
<div id="options_yes_no">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 text-center"></div>
    <div class='span6'>
      <input type="text" class="options" name="option_desc[]" style="width:98%" value="Yes" data-option_field_id="" data-option_id="" />
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="option_other_required" name="other_required[]" /> Other
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-option"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-option"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 text-center"></div>
    <div class='span6'>
      <input type="text" class="options" name="option_desc[]" style="width:98%" value="No" data-option_field_id="" data-option_id="" />
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="option_other_required" name="other_required[]" /> Other
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-option"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-option"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<select id="field_type_id" name="field_type_id" class="span12">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="2" data-alias="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
    <option value="3" data-alias="date">Date</option>
    <option value="5" data-alias="fixed_text">Fixed Text</option>
    <option value="1" data-alias="radio">Radio</option>
    <option value="4" data-alias="text">Text</option>
    <option value="6" data-alias="textarea">Textarea</option>
    <option value="8" data-alias="yes_no">Yes/No</option>
</select>

<button id="me"> Click me</button>
```

PS: if the snippet does not work properly I have setup a Fiddle also [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/508n2zk6/2/)

Comment: Have you verified the function parameters contain what you think they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you click the button, you didn't set the value before you trigger the event, which will leave the selected option to be blank, and then run the default routine in your switch action. Thus none of the input values are actually being set, and you got undefined when trying to print them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = [{
      field_id: 294249,
      field_seq: 36,
      field_type_id: 8,
      form_id: 9926,
      is_base_grid: null,
      option_desc: "Yes",
      option_id: 364371,
      other_required: 0
    }, {
      field_id: 294249,
      field_seq: 36,
      field_type_id: 8,
      form_id: 9926,
      is_base_grid: null,
      option_desc: "No",
      option_id: 364372,
      other_required: 0
    }],
    i = 1,
    k = 1,
    container_yes_no = $("#options_yes_no"),
    field_type = $("#field_type_id"),
    content = '<label>Options</label>\n' +
    '<div id="options_yes_no">\n' +
    '    <div class="row-fluid">\n' +
    '        <div class="span2 text-center"></div>\n' +
    '        <div class=\'span6\'>\n' +
    '            <input type="text"\n' +
    '                   class="options"\n' +
    '                   name="option_desc[]"\n' +
    '                   style="width:98%"\n' +
    '                   value="Yes"\n' +
    '                   data-option_field_id=""\n' +
    '                   data-option_id=""\n' +
    '            />\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '        <div class="span2">\n' +
    '            <label class="checkbox">\n' +
    '                <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="option_other_required" name="other_required[]"/> Other\n' +
    '            </label>\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '        <div class="span2">\n' +
    '            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-option"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>\n' +
    '            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-option"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '    </div>\n' +
    '    <div class="row-fluid">\n' +
    '        <div class="span2 text-center"></div>\n' +
    '        <div class=\'span6\'>\n' +
    '            <input type="text"\n' +
    '                   class="options"\n' +
    '                   name="option_desc[]"\n' +
    '                   style="width:98%"\n' +
    '                   value="No"\n' +
    '                   data-option_field_id=""\n' +
    '                   data-option_id=""\n' +
    '            />\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '        <div class="span2">\n' +
    '            <label class="checkbox">\n' +
    '                <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="option_other_required" name="other_required[]"/> Other\n' +
    '            </label>\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '        <div class="span2">\n' +
    '            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-option"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>\n' +
    '            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-option"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>\n' +
    '        </div>\n' +
    '    </div>\n' +
    '</div>\n';

  field_type.change(function() {
    var field_type_id = $(this).find('option:selected'),
      field_type_name = field_type_id.data('alias');

    switch (field_type_name) {
      case 'yes_no':
        container_yes_no.html(content);
        var i = 1,
          k = 1;

        container_yes_no.find(":text").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("id", "option_desc_" + i);
          console.log("option_desc_" + i);
          i++;
        });

        container_yes_no.find(":checkbox").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("id", "option_other_" + k);
          k++;
        });

        break;
      default:
        console.log(field_type_name);
        break;
    }
  }).trigger('change');

  $("#me").on("click", function() {
    load_edit_question(field_type, options);
  });
});

function load_edit_question(select_el, options) {
  select_el.val('8').trigger('change');
  loadq(options);
}

function loadq(options) {
  console.log(options);

  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var option = options[i],
      curr_opt_desc = $("#option_desc_" + (i + 1)),
      curr_option_other = $("#option_other_" + (i + 1)),
      fullId = option.field_id + '_' + option.option_id;

    curr_opt_desc.val(option.option_desc);
    curr_option_other.prop('checked', option.other_required === 1);
    curr_opt_desc.data("option_id", option.option_id);
    curr_opt_desc.data("option_field_id", option.field_id);

    console.log(fullId);
    console.log(curr_opt_desc.val());
    console.log(curr_opt_desc.data("option_id"));
    console.log(curr_opt_desc.data("option_field_id"));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Options</label>
<div id="options_yes_no">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 text-center"></div>
    <div class='span6'>
      <input type="text" class="options" name="option_desc[]" style="width:98%" value="Yes" data-option_field_id="" data-option_id="" />
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="option_other_required" name="other_required[]" /> Other
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-option"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-option"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 text-center"></div>
    <div class='span6'>
      <input type="text" class="options" name="option_desc[]" style="width:98%" value="No" data-option_field_id="" data-option_id="" />
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="option_other_required" name="other_required[]" /> Other
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-option"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-option"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<select id="field_type_id" name="field_type_id" class="span12">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="2" data-alias="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
    <option value="3" data-alias="date">Date</option>
    <option value="5" data-alias="fixed_text">Fixed Text</option>
    <option value="1" data-alias="radio">Radio</option>
    <option value="4" data-alias="text">Text</option>
    <option value="6" data-alias="textarea">Textarea</option>
    <option value="8" data-alias="yes_no">Yes/No</option>
</select>

<button id="me"> Click me</button>
```